# Problems with Installing Python Packages

Tags: python, xcode, unix

I've seen some past threads that discuss similar problems, but none seem to be having exactly the problem that I am having. I was having problems with installing packages with Python, even though I'd managed to install them before. When I attempted to run gcc, it seemed to not be installed, so I uninstalled Xcode completely and just installed the command line tools (I really only use the command line tools, and could use the extra disk space).

Though the installer said that the installation was successful, gcc results in the following error:

```
 xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory)
```

I have tried to redirect the path by using the following command:

```
 export DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer"
```

It doesn't seem to work, though.

I've also tried using the following command:

```
 sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

but it returns the following error: xcode-select: Error: Path "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer" is not a directory.

Which makes sense I think -- after all, I did uninstall Xcode, so I suppose I should point it to the Command Line tools directory? I'm not sure how to do this, though.

I'm using Mac OS X 10.8.5, by the way.

Comment: Try reinstalling XCode and the command-line tools. You need both.

Comment: Reinstalled both XCode and the command-line tools, I still get the same error.

Comment: Ok, the file path was incorrect. I fixed it using sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/
 and an echo command. It now tells e that there is a version of gcc installed, and recognizes xcode, but I still get a bunch of clang errors when I try to install a python package...